# How to move boilerplate code for permission from activity/fragment to other class

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a lot of confusion with when can you send a context as a parameter and when can you not.

In most of our applications we require at least some runtime permissions, I want to move that code out of the Activity/fragment class and move to let's say a RuntimePermissionManager.

I don't want to move it to the BaseActivity or BaseFragment class, because requesting permissions and performing actions based on the result should have a single class following single responsibility principle.

Below is the code for requesting permissions:

```kotlin
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Perform action
                } else {
                    // Show description
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun permissionCheck(permission: Array<String>, requestCode: Int, permissionGranted:() -> Unit) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,
                                             permission[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            
            permissionGranted()
        } else {
            
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                                              permission,
                                              requestCode)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a class and extend  Application class then oncreate method ask for all permissions

Comment: I think it is better to ask for permission just before performing an action for which they are needed, so that the users are better aware of why is it needed. For some applications, you might want to ask for these permissions at the beginning of the app like share it does, but not for all.

Comment: You can use RxPermissions to get rid of boilerplate

Comment: Or you could create Koltin file and add extension function for Context passing only permissions to it and handling the rest inside that function. With extension approach you will still need to handle permissionResult callback inside each fragment/activity

Comment: I think RxPermission is a better approach. But as I am not using RxJava in my project, I will create a Similar class which would give me a LiveData.